# SharePoint 2013 OAuth Context Token not validating after publish

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have built an Auto-hosted App for SharePoint and during development it works really well.

I was able to send the SPAppToken to my PHP application, decode the context token, construct the access_token and use an API to get user credentials.

I then published my application to create the .app file, uploaded that to my sharepoint site.
I can still decode the SPAppToken using my ClientSecret, however I am not able to generate the access_token.

My code returns an invalid client reference.

```
  {
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "ACS50012: Authentication failed.\r\nTrace ID: 3160fd2a-ffb3-4dc9-9877-e621a6b22a1c\r\nCorrelation ID: e9fdfc0d-3fe6-4bd1-afd5-d1d0c73d338e\r\nTimestamp: 2013-05-17 18:33:15Z",
   "error_codes": [
       50012
   ],
   "timestamp": "2013-05-17 18:33:15Z",
   "trace_id": "3160fd2a-ffb3-4dc9-9877-e621a6b22a1c",
   "correlation_id": "e9fdfc0d-3fe6-4bd1-afd5-d1d0c73d338e"
  }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, and decided to go a different way.

Comment: Hi @Graham, Can I ask what different way you went as I'm having the same error trying to access SharePoint through a provider hosted app using C# server code